Help finding the ellipse equation that passes through four points.
Find the equation of the ellipse that passes through: (-6,4), (-8,1), (2,-4) and (8,-3). use the following structure.
$$
\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2} = 1
$$
i have tried doing a system of equations on this with python, but it only gives me approximations, not really accurate with the actual solution, which is:
$$
\frac{(x-2)^2}{100} + \frac{(y-1)^2}{25} = 1
$$
if somebody haves at least a hint, I would be forever grateful.

Hint: Substitute the point coordinates to get four equations (1) to (4). Now subtract (1) - (2) and (3) - (4) to get two equations which are linear in $h$ and $k$. Solve these, treating $a$ and $b$ as constants. You will get something like $$8h=52-9\frac{a^2}{b^2}$$
and a similar equation for $k$. Now do the same with (1) - (3) and (2) - (4) to get a second equation linking $h$ to $\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}$. From the two equations you can find $h$ and the ratio $\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}$ and then you can find $k$.
I expect you can finish off from here.

(Not the exact way you wanted)
I used python, like you did, but using minimization :
import scipy
import numpy as np

xy = np.array([[-6,4], [-8,1], [2,-4], [8,-3]])
eps = 1e-6
def func(abhk):
    a = abhk[0]
    b = abhk[1]
    h = abhk[2]
    k = abhk[3]
    obj = 0
    for (x, y) in xy:
        # obj += (b**2*(x-h)**2+a**2*(y-k)**2 - a**2*b**2)**2
        obj += ((x-h)**2/(a**2+eps) + (y-k)**2/(b**2+eps) - 1)**2
    return obj
x0 = [1,1,1,1]
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(func, x0)
print(res.x)

The result is
[10.00002805  4.99999158  2.0000171   1.00000271]

as you mentioned.
